# How to recursively combine array in php

Tags: php

I want to combine two arrays into a dictionary.
The keys will be the distinct values of the first array, the values will be all values from the second array, at matching index positions of the key.

```html
<?php

$a=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

$b=[1,1,3,2,1,2,6,8,8];

?>

array_combine($b,$a);

Expected result as

<?php

/*
Value '1' occurs at index 0, 1 and 4 in $b
Those indices map to values 2, 3 and 6 in $a
*/
$result=[1=>[2,3,6],3=>4,2=>[5,7],6=>8,8=>[9,10]];

?>
```

Comment: i dont understand how you get your end array

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow!
In the interest of getting you a response to your question, I have taken the liberty of performing some edits.
In doing so, I have had to make some small assumptions about your question.
I have more clearly explained the algorithm you are attempting to implement, and removed a section of code that appeared to cloud the question.
Finally, I have added a code comment that provided an example of how the result was achieved, for a single array entry. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few PHP array functions.  I'm not aware of one that solves your specific problem.  you might be able to use some combination of built in php array functions but it might take you a while to weed through your choices and put them together in the correct way.  I would just write my own function.

Something like this:

```
function myCustomArrayFormatter($array1, $array2) {
    $result = array();
    $num_occurrences = array_count_values($array1);
    foreach ($array1 AS $key => $var) {
        if ($num_occurrences[$var] > 1) {
            $result[$var][] = $array2[$key];
        } else {
            $result[$var] = $array2[$key];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: I can't accept your answer, because my reputation is less than 15.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$b=[1,1,3,2,1,2,6,8,8];


$results = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < count($b); $x++) {
    $index = $b[$x];
    if(array_key_exists ($index, $results)){
        $temp = $results[$index];
    }else{
        $temp = array();
    }
    $temp[] = $a[$x];
    $results[$index] = $temp;

}

print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this:

```
$res = [];
foreach ($b as $b_index => $b_val) {
    if (!empty($res[$b_val])) {
        if (is_array($res[$b_val])) {
            $res[$b_val][] = $a[$b_index];
        } else {
            $res[$b_val] = [$res[$b_val], $a[$b_index]];
        }
    } else {
        $res[$b_val] = $a[$b_index];
    }
}
var_dump($res);
```

**UPDATE:** another way to do this:

```
$val_to_index = array_combine($a, $b);
$result = [];
foreach ($val_to_index as $value => $index) {
    if(empty($result[$index])){
        $result[$index] = $value;
    } else if(is_array($result[$index])){
        $result[$index][] = $value;
    } else {
        $result[$index] = [$result[$index], $value];
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Youre welcome. Make sure to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.